Issues using Community Toolkit MVVM with WPF .NET 4.7.2
I have a project that I started using WPF in .NET 4.7.2. There are good reasons why I am using 4.7.2 and not something newer. I have added the Community Toolkit MVVM package and then gone through the following steps to address some of the issues:

Migrated packages.config to PackageReference. This step is required by the Community Toolkit (there is an error that specifically mandates doing this step).
Added <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion> to the project. There is an error requiring adding the LangVersion to at least 8.0, but there are other features that necessitate 10.0.
Added <Nullable>enable</Nullable> to the project to enable nullable types. (I found this documented at Enabling and using C# 9 features on older and “unsupported” runtimes by Sergio Pedri.)

At this point my project looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{A6C2E104-39B3-4107-9146-2B8318578E23}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyApp</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyApp</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="MyWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Layout\BaseLayout.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MyWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MyWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Layout\BaseLayout.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>BaseLayout.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Layout\ViewModel\DrawerElement.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Layout\ViewModel\LayoutModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Page Include="Pages\Page1.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MainWindowViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Pages\Page1.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Page1.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\AppIcon.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" />
    <PackageReference Include="MaterialDesignThemes" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>

There are multiple problems that I think have a common root cause.

The Solution Explorer shows errors for the Analyzers.
Sorry about including the image, but this is the only way I know how to show what I see.

As you can see the first error reported states that I should include LangVersion 8.0 or newer in the project. It is already set to 10.0, so I do not understand why this error is here. I think this causes the rest of the unexpected behaviors, but I do not know how to get rid of it.

In the MainWindowViewModel.cs, Intellisense sees no errors, but the compiler cannot find the IncrementCountCommand and IncrementCount2Command.


The content of the MainWindowViewModel.cs is:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace MyApp;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    //This is using the source generators from CommunityToolkit.Mvvm to generate a RelayCommand
    //See: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty
    //and: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(IncrementCountCommand))]
    private int _count;
    
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        
    }

    //This is using the source generators from CommunityToolkit.Mvvm to generate a RelayCommand
    //See: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand
    //and: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/relaycommand
    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanIncrementCount))]
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        Count++;
    }

    private bool CanIncrementCount() => Count < 10;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void ClearCount()
    {
        Count = 0;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(IncrementCount2Command))]
    private int _count2;

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanIncrementCount2))]
    private void IncrementCount2()
    {
        Count2++;
    }

    private bool CanIncrementCount2() => Count2 < 10;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void ClearCount2()
    {
        Count2 = 0;
    }
}

Intellisense finds the IncrementCountCommand in the autogenerated MyApp.MainWindowViewModel.IncrementCount.g.cs file that looks like this:
// <auto-generated/>
#pragma warning disable
#nullable enable
namespace MyApp
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    partial class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>The backing field for <see cref="IncrementCountCommand"/>.</summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.RelayCommandGenerator", "8.3.0.0")]
        private global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand? incrementCountCommand;
        /// <summary>Gets an <see cref="global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.IRelayCommand"/> instance wrapping <see cref="IncrementCount"/>.</summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.RelayCommandGenerator", "8.3.0.0")]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.IRelayCommand IncrementCountCommand => incrementCountCommand ??= new global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.RelayCommand(new global::System.Action(IncrementCount), CanIncrementCount);
    }
}

I do not understand why the compiler seems not to find this autogenerated file and complains about the IncrementCountCommand missing. The second problem is that the autogenerated file does not contain an IncrementCount2Command, although the code in MainWindowViewModel.cs for the two properties is identical (except for the '2').
There are more problems for the DrawerElement.cs, that I think are created by the same root cause. Any help addressing this would help.
Oh, one final note: the same code in .NET 8.0 works just fine. It's when I try to use .NET 4.7.2 that I have these problems.
